# NodeJS environnement variables are always undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a `.env` file which is the following:

```
PORT=5000
```

I first run `source .env` to load the environnement variables.
When I run `echo $PORT`, I see that the variable is set to 5000.

But, as soon as I run my nodeJS script, which contains

```js
if(process.env.PORT === undefined) throw new Error("Missing PORT in process.env");
```

It throws an error because the PORT is undefined.
Even after running the script `echo $PORT` is still 5000.

The expected behavior is that `process.env.PORT` is `5000`.

Comment: What platform (OS) are you using? In Linux or MacOS, you have to explicitly put a shell variable in the environment with `export`.

Comment: You can also do this in any UNIX-like environment: `PORT=5000 node yourprog.js`

Answer (score 0):

as Pointy mentioned it you can pass your environment variable when you start your script.
If you prefer to use a `.env` file and want to access its variables during will have to install and use the `dotenv` package.

Two way for doing that.

- When you start your script: `node -r dotenv/config scriptname.js`
- By importing the dotenv package at the start of your script:

```js
require('dotenv').config();
```

google research: node js process env
answer source: https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/how-to-read-environment-variables-from-nodejs/

Answer (score 0):

Install the dotenv package and import or require dotenv in your index.js file.

```
const express = require("express");

    require("dotenv").config();
    
    
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log(`listening at port ${process.env.PORT}`)
    })
```

Make sure you restart your server after importing the dotenv config.